# How to post a file from a form with Axios

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, axios

Using raw HTML when I post a file to a flask server using the following I can access files from the flask request global:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action='upload_file' role="form" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
```

In flask:

```
def post(self):
    if 'file' in request.files:
        ....
```

When I try to do the same with Axios the flask request global is empty:

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" v-on:change="uploadFile">
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">
</form>

uploadFile: function (event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    axios.post('upload_file', file, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
}
```

If I use the same uploadFile function above but remove the headers json from the axios.post method I get in the form key of my flask request object a csv list of string values (file is a .csv).

How can I get a file object sent via axios?

Comment: @Niklesh yes typo cutting and pasting, I fixed it above, includes double quotes in code.

Comment: did you tried `v-on:change="uploadFile"` with `input` instead of `form` tag ?

Comment: @Niklesh I get same result - data sent as string and picked up by request.form not request.files in flask.

Answer (score 583, accepted):

Add the file to a `formData` object, and set the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`.

```
var formData = new FormData();
var imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);
axios.post('upload_file', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Comment: After posting the files. Do we need to access them from HTTP request or need to access them from parameters on server side.

Comment: @ParthPatel : I am using `$_FILES` to get files in server side as I am using PHP

Comment: Thanks for this post, but I still don't see why we need `FormData`. According to  axios's doc, both `File` and `FormData` are treated as 
**Browser only**, so both ways can be seen equally (https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)

Comment: Awesome ! I was sending 'data:{ data:formData}' which was generating error 412. It worked with `data:formData`

Comment: ATTENTION: the snippet works as-is when run in the context of a browser.  To run in node.js, one needs to pass the headers computed by `formData.getHeaders()` This is a known issue with axios; see for e.g. `https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/789`

Comment: @RishiRaut,  may I ask you to have a look at an `axios` related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470085/vue-js-validation-fails-for-file-upload-in-axios-when-multipart-form-data-used ?

Comment: About the comment by @Hiroki on `File` vs. `FormData`: correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe `File` can be used only if you're uploading a single file and not including any other payload data in the request (like in the answer), but `FormData` is what you'll have to use if you want to submit a collection of data (that is, a form with several fields) in addition to the file(s) (which I suspect is more often the case in real applications).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. After upgrading Axios from 0.26 to new major 1.4.0, we started experiencing this issue when sending images to api. Super strange as our image upload features "all of a sudden" stopped working...

Answer (score 32):

Sample application using Vue. Requires a backend server running on localhost to process the request:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    file: ''
  },
  methods: {
    submitFile() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', this.file);
      console.log('>> formData >> ', formData);

      // You should have a server side REST API 
      axios.post('http://localhost:8080/restapi/fileupload',
          formData, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
          }
        ).then(function () {
          console.log('SUCCESS!!');
        })
        .catch(function () {
          console.log('FAILURE!!');
        });
    },
    handleFileUpload() {
      this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
      console.log('>>>> 1st element in files array >>>> ', this.file);
    }
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/pmarimuthu/pen/MqqaOE

Answer (score 30):

If you don't want to use a `FormData` object (e.g. your API takes specific content-type signatures and `multipart/formdata` isn't one of them) then you can do this instead:

```
uploadFile: function (event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    axios.post('upload_file', file, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': file.type
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: If you use `PUT` to upload file then you may use `application/octet-stream`  as `Content-Type`.  If you upload into Amazon S3 storage using `multipart/formdata` as `Content-Type` it will make your files (images, pdfs, documents) into text files with http header added on top. This will damage the content of the uploaded file. So use `application/octet-stream` when uploading binary files with `PUT` methods.

Answer (score 20):

Sharing my experience with React & HTML input

Define input field

```
<input type="file" onChange={onChange} accept ="image/*"/>
```

Define onChange listener

```
const onChange = (e) => {
  let url = "https://<server-url>/api/upload";
  let file = e.target.files[0];
  uploadFile(url, file);
};

const uploadFile = (url, file) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);
  axios.post(url, formData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      fnSuccess(response);
    }).catch((error) => {
      fnFail(error);
    });
};
const fnSuccess = (response) => {
  //Add success handling
};

const fnFail = (error) => {
  //Add failed handling
};
```

Answer (score 15):

This works for me, I hope helps to someone.

```
var frm = $('#frm');
let formData = new FormData(frm[0]);
axios.post('your-url', formData)
    .then(res => {
        console.log({res});
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error({err});
    });
```

Comment: using Nuxt - this finally worked for me. removing `headers: {  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }` was the only way it would actually send the post after getting a server response from options. I am probably doing something wrong, but it is working and I'm leaving it alone lol

Comment: @JeffBluemel `Content-Type` headers are set automagically. You are supposed to have those undefined.

Answer (score 7):

this is my way:

```
var formData = new FormData(formElement);
// formData.append("image", imgFile.files[0]);
const res = await axios.post(
  "link-handle",
  formData,
  {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

How to post file using an object in memory (like a JSON object):

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as FormData  from 'form-data'

async function sendData(jsonData){
    // const payload = JSON.stringify({ hello: 'world'});
    const payload = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
    const bufferObject = Buffer.from(payload, 'utf-8');
    const file = new FormData();

    file.append('upload_file', bufferObject, "b.json");

    const response = await axios.post(
        lovelyURL,
        file,
        headers: file.getHeaders()
    ).toPromise();


    console.log(response?.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with Axios version `0.25.0 >` to `0.27.2` where `FormData` object in a `PUT` request is not handled correctly if you have `appended` more than one field but is fine with one field containing a file, POST works fine.

Also Axios 0.25.0+ automatically sets the correct headers so there is no need to specify `Content-Type`.

Answer (score -2):

For me the error was the actual parameter name in my controller... Took me a while to figure out, perhaps it will help someone. Im using Next.js / .Net 6

Client:

```
export const test = async (event: any) => {
    const token = useAuthStore.getState().token;
    console.log(event + 'the event')
    if (token) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("img", event);
        const res = await axios.post(baseUrl + '/products/uploadproductimage', formData, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
        return res
    }
    return null
}
```

Server:

```
 [HttpPost("uploadproductimage")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UploadProductImage([FromForm] IFormFile image)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

Error here because server is expecting param "image" and not "img:

```
formData.append("img", event);

 public async Task<ActionResult> UploadProductImage([FromForm] IFormFile image)
```