# How to post a file(pdf,doc) in axios service along with JSON data

Tags: json, file, laravel-5, vuejs2, axios

I want to send PDF/Docs files in axios service along with other JSON data.
I have refered ([Ajax post a file from a form with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/ajax-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios/43014086#43014086)) but it only sends file without any JSON data.

```
 field_value: {}, // here it shows empty object,but it should show File Object
 field_type: "file_upload", 
 is_file_upload: true
```

}

when I console the object before sending request than it shows me a file object in FormData() but it show empty braces when is see it in post request.

Comment: i would convert the file to base64 and appened it along with other JSON datas.

Comment: Thanks Madhu, If I convert file to base64 then how could I identify whether it is PDF or Image or Docx on server side

Comment: when you convert a file or image to base64, the first part starts with the type of a file `data:application/pdf;base64, .....`. using this you can identify the file type.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
//HTML    
<input type="file" @change="onFileChanged" :multiple="multiple" :accept="accept" />
```

Then your javascript code to handle the file input:

```
onFileChanged(event) {
  var files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
  if (!files.length) {
    return;
  }

  var formData = new FormData();

  // Add the File object to the formdata
  if (this.multiple) {
    formData.append("files", files);
  } else {
    formData.append("file", files[0]);
  }

  // Add your data...
  formData.append("data", myData);
}

uploadDocument(formData) {
  return Axios.post('/api/documents', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  });
}
```

Use the formData which you get from file input type to send to the backend.

Then you can do something like this:

```
uploadDocument(formData).then((response) => {
  console.log('data sent');
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Sambor, but your solution only sends files in request, it does not have any other JSON data to send.

Comment: Check the line   // Add your data...
  formData.append("data", myData);