# PHP upload file with api

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I am developing an api endpoint to use with my laravel and vue app.

```
public function avatar(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find(Auth::id());
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'avatar' => 'required'
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()]);
        } else {
            $image = $request->get('avatar');
            //base64_decode($file_data)
            $path = Storage::putFile('avatars', base64_decode($image));

            $user->avatar_url = $path;
            if ($user->save()) {
                //return redirect()->route('user_profile_settings');
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code that I have I tried going off what I found online to accomplish file uploads with an api and using php, but I am getting this error "Call to a member function hashName() on string". The goal of this is to upload the file to a s3 bucket using the putFile method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies here:

```
$image = $request->get('avatar');
$path = Storage::putFile('avatars', base64_decode($image));
```

Per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-uploads), you're going to want to use `$request->file('avatar')` to access the file.

Then, you can do `store('avatars')` to store it in your default storage location.

In short:

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

Comment: Does store put it in s3?

Comment: I don't think that for base64 to images though

Comment: @JohnFreedom `store()` does the same thing `Storage::putFile` does. It'll use whatever the "default" storage method in `config/filesystems.php` is set to. You don't need any base64ing here.

Comment: I am not using php for the frontend I am using due for the frontend so the only way to send the image to my laravel backend is base64 I am passing it with json using axios

Comment: @JohnFreedom It's entirely possible to send the actual file unencoded with Axios. See the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/ajax-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios. Base64 encoding the file adds 33% to the file size, so your users will even thank you for it.

Comment: I used this to make my component. I am still not getting how not to use base 64