# Uploading a CSV or Excel file along with json data through React html form to Django

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I want to submit a form to upload either a csv file or an excel file, and provide additional information provided in the form, e.g. text.

For defining the form and sending the request I use React Bootstrap with axios, and for the api I'm using Django 2.2 with rest-framework.

`request.FILES` is always an empty dict, even if I try setting the Content-Type header to `multipart/form-data`, and then additionally nothing is found in the post data of the request, and printing request.data.get('information') below shows `None` in the Django log. Please help, any support will be greatly appreciated.

See below for code snippets.

**Form definition in render():**

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <FormGroup>
    <Form.Label>Upload file</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="file" onChange={this.handleFile}></Form.Control>
    </FormGroup>

    <Button block bssize="large" disabled={!this.validateForm()} type="submit">
    Submit
    </Button>
</form>
```

**Handling file change:**

```
handleFile = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const fileToUpload = event.target.files[0]
  this.setState({
    fileToUpload: fileToUpload
  })
}
```

**Sending the request:**

```
const payload = {
    file: this.state.fileToUpload,
    information: "somedata"
}

const contentType = "multipart/form-data"
let accessToken = token
var headers = {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
headers['Content-Type'] = contentType
const response = await axios({
    method: "post",
    data: payload,
    url: url,
    headers: headers
});
```

**Django endpoint definition:**

```
class RegisterData(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = (parsers.JSONParser, parsers.MultiPartParser)

    def post(self, request):
        for file in request.FILES.values():
            print(file)

        info = request.data.get('information')
        print(info)
        return Response({"success": "Good job, buddy"})
```

Comment: Check that your call is correct for axios file uploads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios

Comment: Oh, yes. I was sending the post data as a simple dictionary, but when I changed it to a FormData object it appears to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the comments but I'll put it here so it's more visible to users with these issues:

Check that you are using the correct data types and arguments for axios:

[How to post a file from a form with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios)