# Vue: Uploaded files empty when sent to Laravel backend

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have an image uploader from Vuetify that allows a user to add images to upload.  It stores them in a v-model `files`.  Files is an array of file objects shaped like this:

```
this.files = [
   0: {
     lastModified: 1588138776398
     lastModifiedDate: Wed Apr 29 2020 01:39:36 GMT-0400 
     (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
     name: "video-pause.png"
     size: 932
     type: "image/png"
     webkitRelativePath: ""
     }
  ]
```

I then have a button to submit the files to the backend endpoint with this function:

```
uploadAssets: function() {

    axios.post('/upload-images', {
        images: this.files,
    })
    .then(response => {
        debugger
    })
}
```

My Laravel backend controller that should be receiving the images looks like this:

```
public function uploadImages(Request $request)
{
    print $request->file('images');
    if ($request->hasFile("images")) {
        log_info($request->file('images'));
        $files = $request->file('images');
        $stack = [];
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $fileName = Storage::put(shop_id().'/assets/', file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()), ['visibility' => 'public']);
            array_push($stack, $fileName);
        }
        return response()->json($stack);
    }
}
```

My issue is that the print log in the backend method is showing the images as `[{}]`.  I can't tell why the data is not being sent over.

Comment: `$request->images` is not a file you need to loop over each image to process them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios