# How to send a file to axios correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to send a file to axios correctly?

File:

```
const onHandleFileRender = e => {
if(e.target.files[0] !== null) {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  setFileData(file);
}
```

};

Request:

```
newFile = data => {
// data - my img
return axios.post(`${this._url}/api/v1/files`, data, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
});
```

Error:
[image]

Console.log my file:
[image]

UPD:
My request:

```
  newFile = data => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", data);

    return axios.post(`${this._url}/api/v1/files`, formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    });
  };
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post a file from a form with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

**This should work**

```js
newFile = data => {
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", data); //<--------- change the name(image) to anything that your backend requires
return axios.post(`${this._url}/api/v1/files`, formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
});
```