# axios equivalent of http requests?

Tags: node.js, http, axios, medium.com-publishing-api

I want to make the following http request

```
POST /v1/images HTTP/1.1
Host: api.medium.com
Authorization: Bearer 181d415f34379af07b2c11d144dfbe35d
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=FormBoundaryXYZ
Accept: application/json
Accept-Charset: utf-8

--FormBoundaryXYZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="filename.png"
Content-Type: image/png

IMAGE_DATA
--FormBoundaryXYZ--
```

It is [Medium API](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs/blob/master/README.md#34-images)

I have attempted following.

```
var axios = require("axios")

var data = (await axios("https://example.com/image.png")).data;

axios.post("https://api.medium.com/v1/images",{image: data},{
headers: {
 "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data",
 "Authorization" : "Bearer " + process.env.key
}
}).then(x=>console.log(x.data))
```

And I get following error.

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

It uses Medium API to upload image, I want to fetch a remote image, and convert it into multipart/form-data and upload it via API, the HTTP request seems confusing, I want the equivalent axios code, someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using FormData instead of plain object?

Example should be like this

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', data);
axios.post('https://api.medium.com/v1/images', formData, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data",
    "Authorization" : "Bearer " + process.env.key
  }
});
```

Reference: [How to post a file from a form with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios)