# send data from client (reactjs) to server (nodejs) but empty

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform

hi guys i try to upload file from react-nodejs to google clode storage ,
in client when i upload file and console log the file , it show the file array but when i try to send to server side , the array is empty

this is client

```
const [myFile, setmyFile] = useState("");

  const onFileUpload = () => {
    console.log(myFile);
    Axios.post("http://localhost:10000/uploads", { myFile: myFile });
  };

<div>
        <h1>GeeksforGeeks</h1>
        <h3>File Upload using React!</h3>
        <div>
          <input
            type="file"
            onChange={(event) => {
              setmyFile(event.target.files[0]);
            }}
          />
          <button onClick={onFileUpload}>Upload!</button>
        </div>
```

this is server

```
app.post("/uploads", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const myFile = req.body.myFile;
    console.log(myFile);
    const imageUrl = await uploadImage(myFile);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Upload was successful",
      data: imageUrl,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

can someone help me , why "myFile" return "{}"

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios

Comment: not same bro @NjugunaMureithi

Comment: Clearly you need to set the headers right.

Comment: Is the `myFile` object present if you do a `console.log(req.body);`?
Have you tried setting different content types? Did it make any difference?

The way to provide a different Content-Type would be the following:

`Axios.post("http://localhost:10000/uploads", { myFile: myFile },{ headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}});`

Answer (score 1):

Simple way of file uploading with react to node sever is.

**On React here is how you want to handle things using axios**

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('media_file', file_input) // Note the file in quotes is the key that the server will use to retrive the input i.e **file_input** in this case

axios.post(url, data).then(res=>{
    console.log(res)
}).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error)
})
```

**So now how you handle this on your nodejs is like this I will be using formidable as bodyParser very easy to use**

```
const Formidable = require("formidable"); //Meant for body parsing

router.post('/api/file-upload', (req, res)=>{
    const form = new Formidable.InconmingForm();
    form.parse(req, (error, fields, files)=>{
        const {media_file} = files 
        //Destructing 'media_file' remember name that we stated on the client
        // it was 'media_file' now that is what I want to de-structure within files which comes 
        //with formidable

    })

})
```

So now if you log **media_file** you will see all that you need about file then you can continue with your logic of uploading to google cloud

Comment: i get error "(node:5576) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Formidable.InconmingForm is not a constructor"

Comment: You must first run ```npm i formidable``` or ```yarn add formidable``` depending on which package manage you are using then you can now use **formidable**

Answer (score 1):

In client side you have to add your file to `formData` object, and set the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`.

Client side code -

```
const onFileUpload = () => {
  console.log(myFile);
  try {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', myFile)

    Axios.post("http://localhost:10000/uploads", formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error while uploading image to server', error)
  }
};

<div>
 <h1> GeeksforGeeks </h1> <h3 > File Upload using React! </h3>
 <div>
  <input
    type="file"
    onChange={
      (event) => {
        setmyFile(event.target.files[0]);
      }
    }
  />
  <button onClick={onFileUpload}> Upload! </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Server side:

1. You have to use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) or some other npm package to upload the files in the server side.
2. Once image is uploaded to google cloud storage, delete the file from local disk. `finally` block in below code is deleting the file from local disk once image is uploaded successfully or if there is any error in uploading the image.

```js
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)
  }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file')

app.post("/uploads", async (req, res, next) => {

  upload(req, res, async function (error) {
    if (error instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      return res.status(500).json(error)
    } else if (error) {
      return res.status(500).json(error)
    }
    const { filename } = req.file
    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)
    try {
      const options = {
        filename
      }
      const imageUrl = await uploadImage(fileStream, options)
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Upload was successful",
        data: imageUrl,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    } finally {
      fs.unlink(req.file.path, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          console.log('Error on deleting file from the path: ', req.file.path)
        }
        console.log('File deleted successfully from the disk')
      })
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: i try the code , but i got error "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined"

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Can you be little more specific?

Answer (score 1):

As @Akanksha singh mentioned, you need to set the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data` and use the `formData` object on the client side:

```
const onFileUpload = () => {
  console.log(myFile);
  try {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', myFile)

    Axios.post("http://localhost:10000/uploads", formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error while uploading image to server', error)
  }
};

<div>
 <h1> GeeksforGeeks </h1> <h3 > File Upload using React! </h3>
 <div>
  <input
    type="file"
    onChange={
      (event) => {
        setmyFile(event.target.files[0]);
      }
    }
  />
  <button onClick={onFileUpload}> Upload! </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

After testing this, logging the `req.body` on the server side returns a buffer instead of an empty object.

In order to deal with this buffer, which contains the form data, I suggest you follow the steps mentioned in the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#multipart_data) to deal with `multipart/form-data` in Cloud Functions

Here is the code sample from the docs:

```
/**
 * Parses a 'multipart/form-data' upload request
 *
 * @param {Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 * @param {Object} res Cloud Function response context.
 */
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');

// Node.js doesn't have a built-in multipart/form-data parsing library.
// Instead, we can use the 'busboy' library from NPM to parse these requests.
const Busboy = require('busboy');

exports.uploadFile = (req, res) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    // Return a "method not allowed" error
    return res.status(405).end();
  }
  const busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
  const tmpdir = os.tmpdir();

  // This object will accumulate all the fields, keyed by their name
  const fields = {};

  // This object will accumulate all the uploaded files, keyed by their name.
  const uploads = {};

  // This code will process each non-file field in the form.
  busboy.on('field', (fieldname, val) => {
    /**
     *  TODO(developer): Process submitted field values here
     */
    console.log(`Processed field ${fieldname}: ${val}.`);
    fields[fieldname] = val;
  });

  const fileWrites = [];

  // This code will process each file uploaded.
  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename) => {
    // Note: os.tmpdir() points to an in-memory file system on GCF
    // Thus, any files in it must fit in the instance's memory.
    console.log(`Processed file ${filename}`);
    const filepath = path.join(tmpdir, filename);
    uploads[fieldname] = filepath;

    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
    file.pipe(writeStream);

    // File was processed by Busboy; wait for it to be written.
    // Note: GCF may not persist saved files across invocations.
    // Persistent files must be kept in other locations
    // (such as Cloud Storage buckets).
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      file.on('end', () => {
        writeStream.end();
      });
      writeStream.on('finish', resolve);
      writeStream.on('error', reject);
    });
    fileWrites.push(promise);
  });

  // Triggered once all uploaded files are processed by Busboy.
  // We still need to wait for the disk writes (saves) to complete.
  busboy.on('finish', async () => {
    await Promise.all(fileWrites);

    /**
     * TODO(developer): Process saved files here
     */
    for (const file in uploads) {
      fs.unlinkSync(uploads[file]);
    }
    res.send();
  });

  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
};
```