# Current request is not a multipart request : Spring boot

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

Current request is not a multipart request Spring boot error while trying to upload a Image file.

**Spring Boot**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add-item")
public ResponseEntity<?> handleProductInsert ( @RequestParam MultipartFile thumbnailFile ){
  try{
          .....................
          .....................
        return new ResponseEntity("Product added successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return new ResponseEntity("Internal Server Error. Try again later", 
          HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

**React App**

```
state={data:null}

   handleChange=(e)=>{
     this.setState({data:e.target.files[0]});
   }

   connectToDatabase=async()=>{
        return await axios.post(`https://localhost:8080/add-item`, this.state.data);
    }

   render()=>{
       return (<>
                <input accept="image/*" onChange={this.handleChange} type="file" />
                <button onClick={this.connectToDatabase}>Submit</button>
               </>
              )
}
```

Comment: try add `consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }` to `@PostMapping` annotation

Comment: @ДаниилДмитроченков i tried and gets "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported"

Comment: Are you sure `https://localhost:8080/add-item` is correct URL? May be `http://localhost:8080/add-item`? (http instead https)

Comment: Probably you have problem with sending request check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios

Answer (score 0):

try to change `@PostMapping` when `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE` from `import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE;`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add-item", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> handleProductInsert ( @RequestParam MultipartFile thumbnailFile ){
  try{
          .....................
          .....................
        return new ResponseEntity("Product added successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return new ResponseEntity("Internal Server Error. Try again later", 
          HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: I DID THIS, IT SHOWS org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

Answer (score 0):

form-data requires a `key` along with the file in Controller.
Try:

```
@PostMapping(headers = { "Content-Type=multipart/form-data" }, value = "/add-item")
public ResponseEntity<?> handleProductInsert(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile thumbnailFile){
  try{
          .....................
          .....................
        return new ResponseEntity("Product added successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return new ResponseEntity("Internal Server Error. Try again later", 
          HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

On Client Application, prepare request:

```
<form id='form' encType="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input id='import-field' type="file" name="file" accept=".jpg" onChange={onUpload} />
</form>
```

```
const onUpload = event => {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
        let formElement = document.getElementById('import-field');
        uploadFile(new FormData(formElement)); //do POST call here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to specify the content type header

```js
axios.post('upload_file', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Or use a shortcut method `postForm`, which is just the corresponding http method with the `Content-Type` header preset to `multipart/form-data`, see https://github.com/axios/axios#using-multipartform-data-format

```js
axios.postForm('upload_file', formData)
```