# Reactjs. TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON when i try to send data via axios post request to api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

i'm a react newbie. i'm tring to make a post request where i need to send some data. when i make a post request i get "Error:  TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLAnchorElement'
|     property '__reactFiber$65sl5cotq2u' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'
--- property 'stateNode' closes the circle". i can't figure out if the problem has to do with states. this is the link to the git of the backend:https://github.com/Matteoa99/library_backend/blob/main/api/routes/upload.js

````
    user: [],
    book: [],
    genre: [],
    currGen: null,
    titolo: "",
    trama: "",
    quantita: "",
    cover: null,
    error: "",
  };

  static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleFile = this.handleFile.bind(this);
  }

  addNewLibro(titolo, trama, quantita, genere, copertina) {
    genere = this.state.currGen;
    copertina = new FormData();
    copertina.append("image", this.state.cover);
    let JWTToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    axios
      .post(
        "http://g0ptrkwkej5fhqfl.myfritz.net:8090/api/upload/caricaLibro",
        {
          titolo
          genere,
          trama,
          copertina,
          quantita,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `${JWTToken}`,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(JWTToken);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(`Error:  ${error}`));
    this.setState({ error: "Qualcosa è andato storto" });
  }

  doAddNewLibro = async () => {
    this.addNewLibro(
      this.state.titolo,
      this.state.trama,
      this.state.quantita,
      this.state.currGen,
      this.state.cover
    );
  };

  handleFile(e) {
    this.setState({ cover: e.target.files[0] });
  }

  render() {
     return(
<div>
<Form noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <div>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                type="text"
                name="titolo"
                id="titolo"
                value={this.state.titolo}
                label="Titolo"
                autoComplete="titolo"
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
                style={{ marginTop: "25px", marginBottom: "10px" }}
              />
            </div>

            <div>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                type="text"
                name="trama"
                id="trama"
                label="Trama"
                value={this.state.trama}
                autoComplete="trama"
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
                style={{ marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "10px" }}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                type="text"
                name="quantita"
                id="quantita"
                label="Quantità"
                value={this.state.quantita}
                autoComplete="quantita"
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
                style={{ marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "10px" }}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="">
              <label>Seleziona Copertina</label>
              <input
                type="file"
                name="copertina"
                onChange={(e) => this.handleFile(e)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Dropdown onClick={this.getGenre}>
                <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
                  Dropdown Button
                </Dropdown.Toggle>

                <Dropdown.Menu>
                  {this.state.genre.map((genere) => (
                    <Dropdown.Item onClick={this.setGenere} key={genere.ID}>
                      {genere.Descrizione}
                    </Dropdown.Item>
                  ))}
                </Dropdown.Menu>
              </Dropdown>
            </div>
            <Button
              onClick={this.doAddNewLibro}
              variant="contained"
              style={{
                color: "whitesmoke",
                backgroundColor: "#006ddb",
                marginTop: "10px",
                marginBottom: "30px",
              }}
            >
              Invia
            </Button>
            {this.state.error && (
              <Alert color="danger">{this.state.error}</Alert>
            )}
          </Form>
</div>
)
}```
````

Comment: You're trying to send a FormData object as part of another object, I don't think that'll work. Try adding the rest of the data to the FormData object, then send just that.

Comment: could you write an example

Comment: Duplicate: [How to post a file from a form with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios)