# How to post images with axios in flask?

Tags: javascript, forms, flask, axios

I'm trying to post an image using axios

I was earlier using post form method

```
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="/imgUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" autocomplete="off" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    @app.route('/imgUpload', methods=['POST'])
    def upload_image():
        file = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join('/home/user/images', filename))
        return render_template('test.html')
```

How to replicate the same process using axios. Should I add a function for submit and send the image data?

sample axios function:

```
    function getName(name) {
        var user_name = name;
        axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "/send_name",
            params: {
                user_name
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            response_data = response.data["img_data"];
        });
        };
```

What changes should I make to form and the axios function to post an image?

Comment: You need to create formData and populate it with the file binary, then send it with axios. Make sure content-type is set to multiparty/form-data

Comment: Thanks, Any documentation/answer to refer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014086/11024771

Comment: What should be server side request to get the image data