# Get image in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am handling image upload in laravel and vuejs.

In controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
     $data = $request->file;
     return response()->json($data);
  }
```

In vuejs :

```
 data() {
  return: {
    file:null
  }
},

 methods: {
    uploadFile() {
      axios
        .post("/promotion-platform/api/upload/store", {
            file: this.file,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          //result : 
            {file: {…}}
              file:
                $path: null
                __proto__: Object
             __proto__: Object
          //
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
```

Template:

```
<b-form @submit.prevent="uploadFile">
  <b-form-file
     v-model="file"
     placeholder="Choose image..."
  />
</b-form>
```

When I select an image, and press submit, `console.log(res.data)` returns empty, how do I get that image in the controller? Please give me ideas

Comment: I believe this to be a multipart/form data issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios

Comment: It's better to return the URL of the new image instead of the image itself.