# Why am I getting a 500 when uploading file via the browser but not via Postman?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

When I run my API on Postman, the file gets stored in S3 followed by the DB successfully, as depicted in the `FileUploadController.php` file below.  I'm not sure if there's something off in the `Gallery.js` file but my suspicion is that the `name="userUpload"` attribute on the `<input/>` isn't being consumed properly by the `POST` request? But I'm not sure.

When I selected and upload a file on the browser, I get an error when I check the logs that says:

`local.ERROR: Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null at /var/www/app/Http/Controllers/FileUploadController.php:29)`

I'm not sure why `getClientOriginalName()` gets `null` when trying on the browser but seems to work fine, all-around, when trying on Postman.  `console.log(data);` displays the file name correctly, so we can rule that out in terms of it's `undefined` or `null`.

How can I fix this?

Here's `FileUploadController.php` file:

```
public function fileUpload(Request $request)
{

    $path = env('AWS_S3_PATH');
    $file = $request->file('userUpload');
    $imgName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $bucket = env('AWS_BUCKET');
    $region = env('AWS_REGION');
    $url = "https://{$bucket}.s3.{$region}.amazonaws.com{$path}{$imgName}";
    $userId = Auth::user()['UserID'];

    $file->storeAs(
        $path, // Folder
        $imgName, // Name of image
        's3' // Disk Name
    );

    $data = [
        'url' => $url,
        'UserID' => $userId,
        'isUploaded' => true,
        'timeStamp' => time(),
        'updated_at' => time()
    ];

    Upload::create($data);

    return $data;

}
```

Here's `Gallery.js` file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Button, Image, Modal} from "react-bootstrap";

const Gallery = () => {

    const [filePreview, setFilePreview] = useState(null);

    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);

    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const handleFileInput = (e) => {
        setFilePreview(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
        setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }

    const uploadFile = () => {
        const data = {
            'userUpload': selectedFile
        }

        const headers = {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
        }

        console.log(data);

        axios.post('http://localhost:8005/api/file-upload', data, {headers})
            .then(resp => {
                console.log(resp);
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    }

    return (
        <form encType="multipart/form-data">
            <div className="fileUpload text-center">
                <input type="file" onChange={handleFileInput} name="userUpload" required/>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                    Launch demo modal
                </Button>
            </div>

            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Image fluid src={filePreview}/>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => uploadFile()}>Upload!</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>

        </form>
    );
}

export default Gallery;
```

Comment: It looks like the file isn't being uploaded as `multipart/form-data`, which I think is required for the `$_FILES` array to be populated, although I'm not 100% certain if Laravel cares about that

Comment: When you upload files via AJAX, the form's `enctype` is ignored. You need to set the Content-Type header in `headers`. If you want to send additional data along with the file, you might also need to use a FormData object. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014086/1941241) for a basic example.