# Getting error while sending image to an API using formData - React and Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am using formdata to send images to the server but when I use the append function, it does not add anything to formdata that I have declared and I keep getting a 400 error.

```
const fileSelectHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);

    let image = file;
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("image", image);
    console.log(formData);
    
    Axios.post(imgUrl, formData, config)
      .then((response) => console.log("Response: " + response))
      .catch((err) => console.log("error: " + err));
  };
```

and the input:

```
<input
  type="file"
  className="form-control"
  onChange={fileSelectHandler}
/>
```

Comment: check api with postman

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post a file from a form with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios)

Comment: Sending a single file works on postman but when I do it like this from my code, it gives the error

Comment: No, this does not answer my question because that solution is not working for me

Comment: add sample in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: `let image = file;` - what is `file` supposed to be, where does it come from?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-engelbart-7itdf?file=/src/App.js:2012-2040

Comment: Please review the codesandbox

Comment: The file is the value given to the state variable. File is the selected image from the machine

Comment: @HusnainMehmood You can't consume `file` state immediately after updating it (because thats how react manages states). Just use `let image = e.target.files[0]`;

Comment: @HusnainMehmood also dont set `content-type` manually since `multipart/form-data` needs "boundary" value. Leave it empty and axios will do that for you.