# FormData returning as empty object when trying to upload file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask

I am trying to send a file from my React client to my Flask server.

**State that holds file**

```
  const [fileToUpload, setFileToUpload] = useState(null)
```

**form**

```
          <React.Fragment>
            <p className='margin-top' style={pStyles}>Attach your file</p>
            <form onSubmit={handleFileUpload} encType='multipart/form-data'>
              <input
                multi='false'
                type='file'
                onChange={(e) => handleSetFileValues(e)}
              />
              {currentCheck === 'file-radio' ? (
                <button type='submit' className='btn-blue'>Upload</button>
              ) : (
                null
              )}
            </form>
          </React.Fragment>
```

**handleSetFileValues**

```
  const handleSetFileValues = (e) => {
    setFileToUpload(e.target.files[0])
    setFileUrlToUpload('')
  }
```

**handleFileUpload**

```
  const handleFileUpload = async (e) => {
    // if (fileTitle === '' || fileToUpload !== null) return;
    e.preventDefault()

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", fileToUpload);

    const { data, success, errorMessage } = await addServiceFile(service.id, formData, fileTitle)
    if (success) {
      console.log('res', data)
    } else {
      console.log('ERROR', errorMessage)
    }
  }
```

Upon submision I recieve a 400 res from the server. Logging `formData` shows an empty object, and the `file` object in the req payload is an empty object as well. any advice here would be great.

**addServiceFile**

```
export async function addServiceFile(serviceId, fileToUpload, fileLabel) {
  try {
    const body = {
      file: fileToUpload,
      file_label: fileLabel
    };

    return await awsApiRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      path: `/service/${serviceId}/file-data`,
      params: {
        body: body,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
```

**ADDITIONAL CODE**

**awsApiRequest**

```
export const awsApiRequest = async ({
  apiName = API_NAME,
  method = 'GET',
  path = '',
  params,
}) => {
  let apiRequest;
  switch (method) {
    case 'POST':
      apiRequest = API.post(apiName, path, params);
      break;
    case 'PUT':
      apiRequest = API.put(apiName, path, params);
      break;
    case 'PATCH':
      apiRequest = API.patch(apiName, path, params);
      break;
    case 'DELETE':
      apiRequest = API.del(apiName, path, params);
      break;
    case 'HEAD':
      apiRequest = API.head(apiName, path, params);
      break;
    case 'GET':
    default:
      apiRequest = API.get(apiName, path, params);
      break;
  }

  try {
    const responseData = await apiRequest;
    return {
      success: true,
      data: responseData,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      success: false,
      ...getApiErrorData(_.get(error, 'response', {})),
    };
  }
};export const awsApiRequest = async ({
  apiName = API_NAME,
  method = 'GET',
  path = '',
  params,
}) => {
  let apiRequest;
  switch (method) {
    case 'POST':
      apiRequest = API.post(apiName, path, params);
      break;
    case 'PUT':
      apiRequest = API.put(apiName, path, params);
      break;
    case 'PATCH':
      apiRequest = API.patch(apiName, path, params);
      break;
    case 'DELETE':
      apiRequest = API.del(apiName, path, params);
      break;
    case 'HEAD':
      apiRequest = API.head(apiName, path, params);
      break;
    case 'GET':
    default:
      apiRequest = API.get(apiName, path, params);
      break;
  }

  try {
    const responseData = await apiRequest;
    return {
      success: true,
      data: responseData,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      success: false,
      ...getApiErrorData(_.get(error, 'response', {})),
    };
  }
};
```

**Flask Server Code**

```
@bp.route("/service/<int:service_id>/file-data", methods=["POST"])
def add_service_file_data(service_id):
    file = request.files['file']
    file_label = request.json['file_label']

    add_new_service_file_data(service_id, file, file_label)

    response.status_code = 201
    return f'Uploaded succesfully: {file.filename}'
```

**add_new_service_file_data**

```
def add_new_service_file_data(service_id, file, file_label):
    new_file_data = ServiceFile(service_id=service_id, file_data=file.read(), file_label=file_label)

    try:
        db_session.add(new_file_data)
        db.commit()

    except:
        db_session.rollback()
        message = "Error Occured"
```

Comment: What is `awsApiRequest`? And why are you storing a FormData object in a `file` property?

Comment: @ChrisG I added all the additional client and server code

Comment: You posted awsApiRequest twice, but what we need to see is `API.post`

Comment: @ChrisG ```API``` is a hook coming from ```AWSAmplify``` https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/fetch/q/platform/js/ I dont think the problem lies anywhere there as I am getting a response from the server

Comment: As far as I can tell you're posting `{ body: { file: aFormDataObject }}` via (ultimately) axios. I don't think that's going to work. Did you inspect the POST request in the browser's dev tools? You should see a `multipart/form-data` request with a body containing boundaries and your file as binary

Comment: @ChrisG in the payload the file object is in fact empty

Comment: Here's how to upload a file with axios, maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios/43014086#43014086 (bottom line: you need to set the encoding and pass the FormData object directly)