# Javascript transform <input> file to binary

Tags: javascript, axios, binary, filereader

I am trying to transform the file from the input element to raw binary data and then upload it to the server with the help of axios.put

The main/problematic parts of the code in my opinion are:

```
  const file = document.getElementById('file').files[0]

  async function getBinaryFromFile(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(reader.result))
      reader.addEventListener('error', (err) => reject(err))
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
    })
  }

  const binary = await getBinaryFromFile(file)

  const config = {
      data: binary,
      signal: controller.value.signal
   }

  axios.put(`${url}/${uuid}/file/${file.name}`, binary, config)
```

**This is the output if I console.log(binary):**

-----------------------------220913591021183570121419664829

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="Additional-1.pdf"

Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.5
%����
4 0 obj
/Length 5 0 R
/Filter /FlateDecode

stream
x��}[�f7r�����S�z���;   ��r1�8�����a������#;�{2�?\kU��N�zz$��Nշ77Y����dx��a�'����w}�~���u��;�1����_=�������ӷ�x�e���[ZP�/)�������{��o�������#<������o�{���_������w칔���u?�r������7����W��?{��#�Q��|�_rK����1������%�q'�w��C��8^�(�cx���R�\�ܝ��;����s���/c��|ꉈ~�����k��1��p    �|虈��@��Bj�*/�7{x�a��ǅ��&��8���p"����b��(�nV�c��>�۰���Qo���
��|�U���J*�CԻ�勤��E���O֙:����ϳ�  �Z��^���t�����������S�SQC�_`�����~��&9C����.+/#tc����*pr��S���M�=g�\�vH���= |�!�����K�q��&!��$��yL��OG��zW��[to�`Ik����p����mb0�    ��H!+������ RB��[�`~�\�<1ar�dQ�'���D(�DL*EB�^������~\��=��a�u,��Ĺ�
��������'�J���>����Q>e����[�................

If I download the file from the server afterwards I get an error that it cannot be displayed or a blank PDF.
What am I doing wrong here? Why do I get this gibberish?

Comment: _"Why do I get this gibberish?"_ - What do you expect? The bytes of a binary file won't be a well-written essay o.O

Comment: [How to post a file from a form with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you *are* getting gibberish. Remember, a "binary string" is a string containing values that may not have glyphs associated with them in a font.

That said, `readAsBinaryString` isn't how I would do this in new code (and in any case, there's no reason to supply the data *both* as an argument *and* in the `config.data` property). [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects are [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)s, and axios can handle [accepting a blob as `data`](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config):

```
const file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];

const binary = await getBinaryFromFile(file);

const config = {
    data: file, // ***
    signal: controller.value.signal,
};

axios.put(`${url}/${uuid}/file/${file.name}`, config);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but for example after uploading an .jpeg file this way I get following error: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x2d 0x2d when downloading it. Any reason why?

Comment: @Fersek - I suspect it's nothing to do with this code at all.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite easy instead of using `reader.readAsBinaryString(file)` I used `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)` and it works like a charm.