# Send file data with axios to symfony API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, symfony, axios

I've been trying to send a Vcard file with React and Axios on my Symfony API for a few hours now but I can't get a file POST on symfony.

I make my request by retrieving my Vcard file with a file type input, here is my code:

```
        submitFile = (values, actions) => {
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_NAME+"/api/vcard/parser",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Accept': 'multipart/form-data',
      Authorization: "Bearer " + Cookies.get("BEARER")
  },
    data: {
      file: values
    }
  })
```

when I do a dd(Request) on symfony what I get in this case I have this:

```
+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#100
  #parameters: array:1 [
    "file_file" => "C:\fakepath\monfichier.vcf"
  ]
}
```

If I make a request with Postmann and also my dd(Request) I get the expected result and I can retrieve an element of type Request->files:

```
+files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#93
    #parameters: array:1 [
      "file" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#92
        -test: false
        -originalName: "monfichier.vcf"
        -mimeType: "text/x-vcard"
        -error: 0
        path: "C:\wamp64\tmp"
        filename: "phpA068.tmp"
        basename: "phpA068.tmp"
        pathname: "C:\wamp64\tmp\phpA068.tmp"
        extension: "tmp"
        realPath: "C:\wamp64\tmp\phpA068.tmp"
        aTime: 2022-10-04 05:11:21
        mTime: 2022-10-04 05:11:21
        cTime: 2022-10-04 05:11:21
        inode: 281474978677051
        size: 461
        perms: 0100666
        owner: 0
        group: 0
        type: "file"
        writable: true
        readable: true
        executable: false
        file: true
        dir: false
        link: false
        linkTarget: "C:\wamp64\tmp\phpA068.tmp"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Can you give me a little idea of my Axios configuration to make it work? I tried to pass my data through a FormData but without success either.

Thank you in advance

A+ Julien

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post a file from a form with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios)

Comment: Thank's, working fine with this script ;-) Have a nice day